# Convert a JSON string to a struct column without schema in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql, schema

Spark: 3.0.0
Scala: 2.12.8

My data frame has a column with JSON string, and I want to create a new column from it with the StructType.

| temp_json_string |
| --- |
| {"name":"test","id":"12","category":[{"products":["A","B"],"displayName":"test_1","displayLabel":"test1"},{"products":["C"],"displayName":"test_2","displayLabel":"test2"}],"createdAt":"","createdBy":""} |

```
root
 |-- temp_json_string: string (nullable = true)
```

Formatted JSON:

```json
{
  "name":"test",
  "id":"12",
  "category":[
    {
      "products":[
        "A",
        "B"
      ],
      "displayName":"test_1",
      "displayLabel":"test1"
    },
    {
      "products":[
        "C"
      ],
      "displayName":"test_2",
      "displayLabel":"test2"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt":"",
  "createdBy":""
}
```

I want to create a new column of type Struct so I tried:

```
dataFrame
     .withColumn("temp_json_struct", struct(col("temp_json_string")))
     .select("temp_json_struct")
```

Now, I get the schema as:

```
root
 |-- temp_json_struct: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- temp_json_string: string (nullable = true)
```

Desired result:

```
root
 |-- temp_json_struct: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- displayLabel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- createdAt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- updatedAt: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**json_str_col** is the column that has JSON string. I had multiple files so that's why the fist line is iterating through each row to extract the schema. If you know your schema up front then just replace `json_schema` with that.

```py
json_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.json_str_col)).schema
df = df.withColumn('new_col', from_json(col('json_str_col'), json_schema))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
// import spark implicits for conversion to dataset (.as[String])
import spark.implicits._

val df = ??? //create your dataframe having the 'temp_json_string' column

//convert Dataset[Row] aka Dataframe to Dataset[String]
val ds = df.select("temp_json_string").as[String]

//read as json
spark.read.json(ds)
```

[Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json(jsonDataset:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BString%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: The explanation is in the comments. What more should i explain

Comment: A good explanation might not only contain the code and what the code is doing, but also **why** you choose to do it this way, especially if a question already contains other answers

Comment: Simple and elegant. For some reason, none of the other answers worked on my instance (either missing ``lambda``, ``schema_of_json`` or ``toDS`` methods), but no problems here!

Answer (score 5):

There at least two different ways to retrieve/discover the schema for a given JSON.

For the illustration, let's create some data first:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

val jsData = Seq(
  ("""{
    "name":"test","id":"12","category":[
    {
      "products":[
        "A",
        "B"
      ],
      "displayName":"test_1",
      "displayLabel":"test1"
    },
    {
      "products":[
        "C"
      ],
      "displayName":"test_2",
      "displayLabel":"test2"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt":"",
  "createdBy":""}""")
)
```

**Option 1: schema_of_json**

The first option is to use the built-in function [schema_of_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#schema_of_json). The function will return the schema for the given JSON in DDL format:

```scala
val json = jsData.toDF("js").collect()(0).getString(0)

val ddlSchema: String = spark.sql(s"select schema_of_json('${json}')")
                            .collect()(0) //get 1st row
                            .getString(0) //get 1st col of the row as string
                            .replace("null", "string") //replace type with string, this occurs since you have "createdAt":"" 

// struct<category:array<struct<displayLabel:string,displayName:string,products:array<string>>>,createdAt:null,createdBy:null,id:string,name:string>

val schema: StructType = StructType.fromDDL(s"js_schema $ddlSchema")
```

Note that you would expect that `schema_of_json` would also work on the column level i.e:  `schema_of_json(js_col)`, unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected therefore we are forced to pass a string instead.

**Option 2: use Spark JSON reader (recommended)**

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json

val schema: StructType = spark.read.json(jsData.toDS).schema

// schema.printTreeString

// root
//  |-- category: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- displayLabel: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- products: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
//  |-- createdAt: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- createdBy: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

As you can see, here we are producing a schema based on `StructType` and not a DDL string as in the previous case.

After discovering the schema we can move on to the next step which is converting the JSON data into a struct. To achieve that we will use [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json) built-in function:

```scala
jsData.toDF("js")
      .withColumn("temp_json_struct", from_json($"js", schema))
      .printSchema()

// root
//  |-- js: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- temp_json_struct: struct (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- category: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- displayLabel: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- products: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
//  |    |-- createdAt: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- createdBy: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to quickly debug or dig into data, a simple SQL solution you can pretty easily implement is to work out the schema yourself.

e.g.

```
strJsonContent
--------------
[{"a":1,"b":"xyz"}, {"a":2,"b":"xyz"}]
```

Schema would be:

```
ARRAY<STRUCT<`a`: BIGINT, `b`: STRING>>
```

Want to put this into a query:

```
select 
  from_json(strJsonContent, 'ARRAY<STRUCT<`a`: BIGINT, `b`: STRING>>')) as structured_strJsonContent, *
  from tableName
```