# Return dataframe array of a nested json array string

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The files are getting stored in a folder, and there's no fixed structure to it. In some files few of the columns may appear and in some it may not. And because of this it is first being stored as a json string. However in the next step I'd want to retrieve it back to its original state(as JSON) and perform the further transformation to it. This is where I'm getting stuck at.

Initially I thought of a recursive approach. Will traverse the json strings and if there are no further columns that are to be traversed of, it will simply return back and feed the values and if there are it will recursively iterate until the above condition is not met. But was not able to implement it.

Can anyone suggest some method to achieve this in pyspark dataframe.
The final schema should be like this.

```
root
 |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- end_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- project_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- release_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- start_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- target_release_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- test-cycles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- target_build_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- target_release_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- test-cycles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- target_build_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- target_release_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- test-cycles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- target_build_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- target_release_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- test-cycles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- target_build_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- target_release_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- test-cycles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- target_build_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- target_release_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- test-cycles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- target_build_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- target_release_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- test-cycles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- target_build_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- target_release_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- test-cycles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- test-suites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- test-suites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- test-suites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- test-suites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- test-suites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- test-suites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- test-suites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_value_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test-suites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field_value_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- web_url: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Check a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031385/convert-a-json-string-to-a-struct-column-without-schema-in-spark/64077996#64077996