# spark scala kafka avro deserializer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, deserialization, avro, spark-structured-streaming

I am consuming a streaming dataframe from kafka. The data in value column is in avro. I want to deserialize the data into struct type.

Currently I have written a udf function which calls the method `public Object deserialize(String topic, byte[] bytes)` present in `KafkaAvroDeserializer`. I am calling this udf function on the value column of the streaming dataframe. The udf function successfully returns the json string.

I want that instead of the json string I should get struct type in value column.
For example now I am getting `{"name": "ABC", "age": 17}` instead I want value column to be of struct type so that I can write `value.name` or `value.age`.

Problem is that I do not have a case class or a sample json or a schema file to convert the json string into struct type. The same code can be used for different topics which have different data.

Any guidance will be very helpful. Please let me know if I am thinking in the wrong way or doing the deserialization in the wrong way.

udf function code

```
  val kafkaAvroDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer()
  private val kafkaAvroDeserializerConfig: Map[String, Any] = Map(
    "schema.registry.url" -> //url for schema registry
  )
  kafkaAvroDeserializer.configure(kafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.asJava, false)

  val deserializationFunction: UserDefinedFunction = udf((input: Array[Byte]) => {
      val genericRecord = kafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize("topic", input)
        .asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]
      genericRecord.toString // currently returns json string successfully
 }
```

utilising the udf method (Data is a simple case class with key: String and value: String)

```
      streamingDF.selectExpr("key", "value")
        .as[Data]
        .select(col("key"), deserializationFunction(col("value")).as("value"))
```

This is not a duplicate question. I got a prompt that if the other question was helpful in answering my question. I clicked on yes because it gave me more insight. I had no idea it would close my question and mark it as duplicate. I had replied same in comments earlier. I have gone through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031385/convert-a-json-string-to-a-struct-column-without-schema-in-spark). The solutions provided almost work as expected. There are a couple of small issues. The first solution is showing deprecated in my ide. The second solution does not include other columns like key, topic, offset. Both the solutions do not work on streaming dataframe unless I use foreachbatch. Honestly I was expecting a solution around the udf function.

Comment: How do you plan to use the data once deserialized from JSON if you don't know what's inside the JSON?

Comment: Hi @GaëlJ. Sorry for the delayed response. I have gone through the link provided. The solutions provided almost work as expected. There are a couple of small issues.
The first solution is showing deprecated in my ide.
The second solution does not include other columns like key, topic, offset.
Both the solutions do not work on streaming dataframe unless I use foreachbatch.
Honestly I was expecting a solution around the udf function.

Comment: Also am I thinking in the wrong direction if I expect that I should be able to deserialize the avro record without knowing the case class or the schema of the value column?
Do you have idea on basis of experience as to how deserialization is usually done in such situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now have a JSON string, so Avro isn't really relevant.

You can use `get_json_object` with a JsonPath expression.

Otherwise, plenty of options shown here [Integrating Spark Structured Streaming with the Confluent Schema Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-confluent-schema-registry)

Comment: Hi sorry for the delayed response. get_json_object requires path. I wanted to find out if I can convert the json to a case class object without knowing the schema of the json string. From all the examples I have realized that it is mandatory to know the schema or case class to convert the json string to an object.

Comment: Indeed. But you have Avro. Therefore you know the schema and can get the schema from that, not use JSON or case classes. See linked post that shows `avroSchemaToSparkSchema` function that you can use with `get_json_object`. Also checkout https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS